# Minimizing proof environment change while proving in Lean

Tags: lean

As a matter of (Lean) style, I would like to minimize changing the proof environment, and instead apply lemmas directly  (to be "less imperative" and "more functional").

So, can the following example provided by [Glimpse of Lean](https://github.com/PatrickMassot/GlimpseOfLean/blob/master/GlimpseOfLean/Introduction.lean)

> if `f` is continuous at `x₀` then  for any sequence `u` converging to `x₀`, the sequence `f ∘ u`
> converges to `f x₀`

where we have the expected definitions

```
import GlimpseOfLean.Library.Basic

namespace Introduction

def seq_limit (u : ℕ → ℝ) (l : ℝ) : Prop := ∀ ε > 0, ∃ N, ∀ n ≥ N, |u n - l| ≤ ε

def continuous_at (f : ℝ → ℝ) (x₀ : ℝ) : Prop := ∀ ε > 0, ∃ δ > 0, ∀ x, |x - x₀| ≤ δ → |f x - f x₀| ≤ ε
```

and which is written in the original style

```
example (f : ℝ → ℝ) (u : ℕ → ℝ) (x₀ : ℝ) (hu : seq_limit u x₀) (hf : continuous_at f x₀) :
  seq_limit (f ∘ u) (f x₀) := by {
  unfold seq_limit;intros ε hε  -- Fix a positive number `ε`.

  obtain ⟨δ, δ_pos, Hf⟩ : ∃ δ > 0, ∀ x, |x - x₀| ≤ δ → |f x - f x₀| ≤ ε := hf ε hε
  obtain ⟨N, Hu⟩ : ∃ N, ∀ n ≥ N, |u n - x₀| ≤ δ := hu δ δ_pos

  use N
  intros n hn   -- Fix `n` which is at least `N`. Let's prove `|f(u_n) - f(x₀)| ≤ ε`.
  apply Hf  -- Thanks to (1) applied to `u_n`, it suffices to prove that `|u_n - x₀| ≤ δ`.
  exact Hu n hn
  }
```

be rewritten in a "more functional" style which I think is more straightforward, like so ?

```
example (f : ℝ → ℝ) (u : ℕ → ℝ) (x₀ : ℝ) (hu : seq_limit u x₀) (hf : continuous_at f x₀) :
  seq_limit (f ∘ u) (f x₀) := by {
  unfold seq_limit; intros ε hε -- Fix a positive number `ε`.

  obtain ⟨δ, δ_pos, Hf⟩ : ∃ δ > 0, ∀ x, |x - x₀| ≤ δ → |f x - f x₀| ≤ ε := hf ε hε
  obtain ⟨N, Hu⟩ : ∃ N, ∀ n ≥ N, |u n - x₀| ≤ δ := hu δ δ_pos

  use N
  Hf Hu
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you actually try? Lean is meant to be used interactively, you don't have to guess whether something is correct. Your last line doesn't make sense. If you want to finish the proof by giving a proof term you can write `exact fun n hn ↦ Hf (u n) (Hu n hn)`. But this is definitely not meant to be a beginner-friendly style. You can simply compare reading the proof given in the project, looking at the tactic state at the end of each line with reading the full proof term:

```
example (f : ℝ → ℝ) (u : ℕ → ℝ) (x₀ : ℝ) (hu : seq_limit u x₀) (hf : continuous_at f x₀) :
  seq_limit (f ∘ u) (f x₀) := 
fun ε hε ↦ (hf ε hε).elim (fun δ ⟨δ_pos, Hf⟩  ↦ (hu δ δ_pos).elim (fun N Hu ↦ ⟨N, fun n hn  ↦ Hf (u n) (Hu n hn)⟩))
```

Note that deep inside Lean there are only such proofs. The imperative style is only here to help users interactively build proofs, but behind the scene it always construct functional proofs (but completely unreadable ones when rewriting or powerful automation is involved).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer to my naive question. Indeed readability is a key quality to reduce the gap between "normal" and formal math.

Comment: one drawback with `intros n hn` is that I (think I) can't type annotate `hn`. Whereas I can do that `  exact fun n (hn : n ≥ N) ↦ (Hf (u n) (Hu n hn : |u n - x₀| ≤ δ) : |f (u n) - f x₀| ≤ ε)`. It would be nice to have "exact" be omitted like return can be omitted in ocaml., if it makes sense, to reduce syntactic burden